# How To Use Getter Setter Method In Laravel? And How To Add Field Using Eloquent Model?

Tags: laravel

**This is my User.php Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname','lastname', 'email','image', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**this is output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [firstname] => admin
            [lastname] => Gomez
            [email] => admin@admin.com
            [image] => admin.png
            [created_at] => 2019-11-10 04:30:01
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-10 14:03:38
        )

)
```

**I just want full path of url using getter setter method using eloquent Model**

Like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [firstname] => admin
            [lastname] => Gomez
            [email] => admin@admin.com

            [image] => public/images/admin.png

            [created_at] => 2019-11-10 04:30:01
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-10 14:03:38
        )

)
```

I also i want add another field like fullname (Like [fullname] => admin gomez )

i want also this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [firstname] => admin
            [lastname] => Gomez
            [email] => admin@admin.com
            [image] => admin.png
            [created_at] => 2019-11-10 04:30:01
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-10 14:03:38

            [fullname] => admin gomez
        )

)
```

**Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please define these two methods in your model:

```
protected $append = ['full_name'];

/**
 * Get the user's full name.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}

/**
 * Get full image path
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getImageAttribute()
{
    if ($this->image) {
        return public_path($this->image);
    }

    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The getter for image on the User model would look something like this:

```
public function getImageAttribute()
{
    return public_path('images') . $this->image;
}
```

The full name one would be exactly what is in the documentation minus the underscores in your case:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}
```

If you're trying to make sense of how or why this works it is because Laravel makes use of PHP's magic methods. In this case the __get. So the model basically looks for any gets and uses the 'get**FieldName**Attribute' method instead if it exists.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get